# How to interprete 寄る in this sentence

Tags: grammar

For full context, see here:
https://www.docdroid.net/67MgwSw/img-20170910-0001-new.pdf

the following excerpt is from the very last line:
じゃ、帰りに旅行会社に寄って、調べてみます。

=> "Well, coming home I will try to research travel agency coming close/being close."

"Coming close" refers to the criteria mentioned by the partner in dialogue before (see link). However, I'm still not really wether I interpreted the context correctly. Furthermore, what irritates me is that in my interpretation, 旅行会社 is the direct object of 調べてみます. There is no を or any other particle though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[寄る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/228575/meaning/m0u/) here should take this meaning:

> ３ ある所へ向かう途中で、他の所を訪れる。立ち寄る。「出社前に得意先に―・る」「帰りに飲みに―・る」

On the way to some place, stop by at another place.

And 旅行会社 is not the direct object 調べてみる. XXXに寄る here means "stop by XXX".

The whole sentence should be:

On my way home, I will stop by the travelling agency and check (it).